# how can i play pause iframe youtube video when scroll using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have added this javascript from https://jsbin.com/cocatuta/15/edit?js,output. I just want to make it work for me. The height of my iframe is greater than than the iframe in the above mentioned link. So the video pauses immediatly after i start scolling. Another issue i am facing is that it does not play again when i scroll up. here is the code  I have.

HTML

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 wow pulse">

   <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xAEGDMeYz-Y?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1;showinfo=0;"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
  //play when video is visible
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"), fraction = 0.1;

function checkScroll() {

  for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    var video = videos[i];

    var x = 0,
        y = 0,
        w = video.width,
        h = video.height,
        r, //right
        b, //bottom 
        visibleX, visibleY, visible,
        parent;


    parent = video;
    while (parent && parent !== document.body) {
      x += parent.offsetLeft;
      y += parent.offsetTop;
      parent = parent.offsetParent;
    }

    r = x + parseInt(w);
    b = y + parseInt(h);


    visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
    visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));


    visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);


    if (visible > fraction) {
      playVideo();
    } else {
      pauseVideo();

    }
  }

};


var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
};

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);

    //check at least once so you don't have to wait for scrolling for the    video to start
    window.addEventListener('load', checkScroll, false);
};


function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      //console.log("event played");
    } else {
      //console.log("event paused");
    }
};

function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
};

function playVideo() {
  player.playVideo();
};

function pauseVideo() {
  player.pauseVideo();
};



  </script>
```

Comment: Can Anyone Explain the Javascript code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest you take some time to look into this topic yourself, start with the basics, rather than using code you don't understand in the first place and expect someone to explain it to you after you've used it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am having an assignment and everything is working fine but I don't understand how they are using width ? is it the width of iframe or whole body?

Comment: Do you mean the `width="640"` attribute in the HTML or `video.width` in JavaScript?

Comment: I am talking about video.width

Comment: The problem I am facing is that videos stop when i scroll down but does not play again when i scroll up.can help you me resolve this issue?

Comment: The `width` attribute comes from the object `video`. The `video` object is created for every 'video' that exists in the array of `videos`. The array `videos` is built by finding every `iframe` tag in your HTML page. So `video.width` corresponds to the `width="640"` attribute, which has the value of `640` pixels